# Is "disputable exceptions" apt in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, academic-writing

> With some disputable exceptions, he did not understand that ....

Could I use "disputable exceptions" in this context? This extract is from an academic text I am editing. The phrase feels clunky, but it is hard to explain why.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Consider adding at least the rest of the sentence as more context.

Comment: That suggests to me that he did not understand the whatevers, except for some of them, but there might be dispute about each of those exceptions (the ones he might not have understood). It actually does not say much, so I would agree with inviting the author to change it.

Comment: It seems like it may be ambiguous what's being disputed.

Comment: I actually like it, and it's a common construct. If I wanted a change, I'd edit to "With some exceptions."